# Shall I model article category as value object when design with DDD?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am learning DDD recently and struggling with modelling article category. The logic of the article management system is as follow.

We have a system that can manage articles. Each article can belong to multiple categories and one category can have multiple articles.

```
class Category: IValueObject
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
}

class Article: IAggregateRoot
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string Content { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

After reading articles and books, I am very confused what type of domain model that Category should be modelled. Seems like it is reasonable to model it as either value object or aggregate root.

For value object, I feel like Category is identified by the Name property. If two Categories with the same Name, it is safe to say they are the same category. In addition, category is a property of article so it may be good to stay in the domain of article.

For aggregate root, I am thinking of having a standalone webpage to CRUD categories, including assigning an article to a category in the category management page, rather than in article detail page (where we can update content and attributes of an article). Seems like modelling the Category to value object will not be able to achieve this.

Can I please get some advice on it? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can represent Category in different ways depends on business logic you plan to develop to solve certain problem.

For example, you can have next Bounded Contexts:

1. **CategoryManagement** - In this Context Category can be represented as Aggregate Root - here you will manage Category changes, validate correctness of Category data for making sure that it valid to be stored/updated in DB, protect Articles invariants (for example, making sure that in certain Category the same Article cannot be added twice etc.)
2. **ArticleManagement** - in this Context Article will be an Aggregate Root, Category here can be represented as ValueObject, for example, for just showing it as an information for editor.

Comment: hmm...this is very interesting. Thank you, @Elenka29 for giving this advice. Does it means, I will have two domain models to represent Category, one is Aggregate Root and the other one is Value Object. The only differences is that the Aggregate Root has an id but not for the Value Object. Haven't seen this in other articles.

Comment: Yes, exactly. In one BoundedContext Category will be responsible for it's lifecycle, when in another Context - it will be just ValueObject holding information and some required business logic in it. I like how this idea was described in this [article] (https://culttt.com/2014/12/15/using-entities-different-bounded-contexts/). There are examples in PHP, but in overall idea is clear, that Entity can be represented differently in various contexts.

Comment: Thank you @Elenka29, this really is an interesting article. Being different types of domain models in different BoundedContexts makes things lots flexible,

Answer (score -1):

> After reading articles and books, I am very confused what type of domain model that Category should be modelled. Seems like it is reasonable to model it as either value object or aggregate root.

This confusion really isn't your fault.

Part of the problem is that your attention is focused on data; but from the point of view of modeling, the thing we really care about is how that data changes over time.

The information that you are showing here (name, description, title, content) all look suspiciously like copies of information that come from somewhere else -- somebody hit a save button, and tada! you store a copy of that data.

In other words, this looks like a data model for a database.  Which is fine - but it's not quite the kind of problem that the DDD patterns are usually applied to.  The distinctions of entities and value objects, and the use of aggregates for life cycle management, lose a lot of their power when you aren't actually managing any of the change in code.

In a domain model where the Article "aggregate" is responsible for its own changes, the clues for how to handle category would be in the requirements that describe how articles change when you get new information.

Comment: Hi VoiceOfUnreason, thank you for your advice. Based on what you mentioned in the last paragraph, can I understand that what Category should be modelled based on its behaviour when an article change is made? For example, when I add a new article, I am able to either create a new category or select an existing category. But we will not be able update the name or description in the article creation page. We would like to enable this update feature in category management page.

Seems like it's more reasonable to model category as an aggregate root.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Ben Once a `Category` has been assigned to an `Article`. If the `Category` changes, should those changes get reflected on the `Article`? If they do then `Category` is most likely an AR or else you will have to update all `Article` instances.

Comment: Hi @plalx, in the example code, an `Article` refers to a list of `Category`. So if we change the `Name` of the first `Category` in the list from the `Category` management page, the new `Name` should be reflected in the first `Category` in the list. Not sure if this makes sense to you.